# It it possible to use two or three ref in one object table?

Tags: sql, oracle

It it possible to use two or three ref in one object table? I am creating a table for a match schedule and i need to have 2 teams in that table which is team 1 and team 2 which should point at the Team table. I am new to Object oriented oracle and i have no idea what i am doing.

Comment: I think the term is 'relational' and yes, it is possible. Just create two fields and two referential constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object tables can contain multiple [references](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjint.htm#CHDCAIAF) as demonstrated below.

```
--Create types and tables.
create or replace type team_type is object
(
    id number,
    name varchar2(100)
);

create table team of team_type;

create or replace type match_type is object
(
    id number,
    match1 ref team_type,
    match2 ref team_type
);

create table match of match_type;

--Sample inserts.
insert into team values(1, 'A');
insert into team values(2, 'A');

insert into match values(
    1,
    (select ref(t) from team t where id = 1),
    (select ref(t) from team t where id = 2)
);
```

As you have discovered, Oracle's object-relational features are very rarely used outside of the classroom.  Asking even the simplest question about them will often cause confusion.  99.9% of the world would use Gordon's answer to implement a relational model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want just using relational database design.  Your table might look something like:

```
create table matches (
    matchid int primary key,
    team1_id int references teams(id),
    team2_id int references teams(id),
    . . .
);
```

Comment: The thing is this has to be done using Oracle features. It is part of my assignment. The Match Schedule has 3 attributes team 1, team 2, and the team won and these 3 attributes needs to be referenced to Team Table or is there any other alternative way?

Comment: There are other ways.  This is how I would do it.